# CSV to JSON of Lists

Tags: python, json, list

Currently, I have a CSV file with the following example --

| File | skill | experience | overall_experience |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Java | 1.5 | 3 |
| 1 | Python | 1.0 | 3 |
| 1 | SQL | 0.5 | 3 |

There are multiple entries for many such files but I need to merge the skills and their respective experience into a single value belonging to a single key, something like this -

```
{
"1": {
    "file": "1",
    "skill": ["Java", "Python", "SQL"],
    "experience": [1.5, 1.0, 0.5]
    "Overall_exp": 3.0
},}
```

I tried a Python Code for this but it is giving me only the value of last skill and last experience (and not the whole thing in a list)

Here is the code I was using --

```
import csv
import json


# Function to convert a CSV to JSON
# Takes the file paths as arguments
def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    # create a dictionary
    data = {}
    # Open a csv reader called DictReader
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        # Convert each row into a dictionary
        # and add it to data
        for rows in csvReader:
            # Assuming a column named 'file' to
            # be the primary key
            key = rows['file']
            data[key] = rows

    # Open a json writer, and use the json.dumps()
    # function to dump data
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))




# Decide the two file paths according to your
# computer system
csvFilePath = 'skill_matrix.csv'
jsonFilePath = 'skill_matrix.json'

# Call the make_json function
make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

The output that I get here is this  --

```
{
"1": {
    "file": "1",
    "skill": "SQL",
    "experience": "0.5"
    "Overall_exp": "3.0"
},}
```

How can I convert it to the former json format and not the latter?

Comment: that output format is unusal. Usually you would have a 2d array where the first array is the header row.

Answer (score 0):

I think that loading into Pandas first and then going from all data to the narrowing strategy is cleaner and easier. You can use the following code for parsing your data into JSON files;

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Load the CSV into Pandas
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', header=0)
data = df.to_dict(orient='list')

# Delete / change as you wish 
data['File'] = str(data['File'][0])
data['overall_experience'] = data['overall_experience'][0]

# Save as json 
with open('1.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
    jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

> **Result (1.json)**

```
{
    "File": "1",
    "skill": [
        "Java",
        "Python",
        "SQL"
    ],
    "experience": [
        1.5,
        1.0,
        0.5
    ],
    "overall_experience": 3
}
```

---

I suppose hat you have multiple file id in a CSV file. Your given example is too minimalistic. Anyhow, then you can create a master dictionary and add your smaller ones as follows;

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Load the CSV into Pandas
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', header=0)

# Master dictionary
master_dict = {}

for idx, file_id in enumerate(df["File"].unique()):
  data = df[df['File'] == file_id].to_dict(orient='list')

  # Delete / change as you wish 
  data['File'] = str(data['File'][0])
  data['overall_experience'] = data['overall_experience'][0]

  master_dict[idx] = data

# Save as json 
with open('1.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
    jsonf.write(json.dumps(master_dict, indent=4))
```

> **Result (1.json)**

```
{
    "0": {
        "File": "1",
        "skill": [
            "Java",
            "Python",
            "SQL"
        ],
        "experience": [
            1.5,
            1.0,
            0.5
        ],
        "overall_experience": 3
    },
    "1": {
        "File": "2",
        "skill": [
            "Java",
            "Python"
        ],
        "experience": [
            2.0,
            2.5
        ],
        "overall_experience": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to read your csv, group by File and export to json:

```
df = pd.read_csv(your_csv)
df = df.groupby('File', as_index=False).agg({'skill': list, 'experience': list, 'overall_experience': np.mean})
print(df.to_json(orient='index', indent=4))
```

Note: you can specify the aggregation functions for your columns in a dictionary

Output:

```
{
    "0":{
        "File":1,
        "skill":[
            "Java",
            "Python",
            "SQL"
        ],
        "experience":[
            1.5,
            1.0,
            0.5
        ],
        "overall_experience":3.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Pandas, you could try:

```
import csv
import json

def make_json(csvfile_path, jsonfile_path):
    data = {}
    with open(csvfile_path, "r") as csvfile:
        next(csvfile)  # Skip header line
        for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
            fdata = data.setdefault(row[0], {"file": row[0]})
            fdata.setdefault("skill", []).append(row[1])
            fdata.setdefault("experience", []).append(float(row[2]))
            fdata.setdefault("overall_experience", []).append(float(row[3]))
    with open(jsonfile_path, "w") as jsonfile:
        json.dump(data, jsonfile)
```

The main difference to your approach is the explicit structuring of the inner dicts: values are lists (except for the `'file'` key). The [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) is great here: You can set a value for a key if it isn't in the dict, and get the value back (either the newly set one or the existing). So you can put a list in the dict, get it back, and can immediately `.append()` to it.

If you want to use a `csv.DictReader`:

```
def make_json(csvfile_path, jsonfile_path):
    data = {}
    with open(csvfile_path, "r") as csvfile:
        for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
            fdata = data.setdefault(row["file"], {"file": row["file"]})
            for key, value in list(row.items())[1:]:
                fdata.setdefault(key, []).append(
                    value if key == "skill" else float(value)
                )
    with open(jsonfile_path, "w") as jsonfile:
        json.dump(data, jsonfile)
```

(I haven't, since I wasn't sure about the actual column names.)